# Recommended Working Hours JSON Format

Tags: json, format

I'm wondering what the best way would be to express an agency's working hours in JSON format. Let's say the agency works 5 days a week (not necessarily Monday to Friday) and works two shifts a day (again, not necessarily): from 9am to 1pm and from 2pm to 6pm. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
{ "Hours" : 
    [ 
    { "Monday": 
        [
            { "Start": "0900", "Finish": "1300" },
            { "Start": "1400", "Finish": "1800" }
        ]
    },
    { "Tuesday":
        [
            { "Start": "0900", "Finish": "1300" },
            { "Start": "1400", "Finish": "1800" }
        ]
    },
    { "Wednesday":
        [
            { "Start": "0900", "Finish": "1300" },
            { "Start": "1400", "Finish": "1800" }
        ]
    },
    { "Thursday":
        [
            { "Start": "0900", "Finish": "1300" },
            { "Start": "1400", "Finish": "1800" }
        ]
    },
    { "Friday":
        [
            { "Start": "0900", "Finish": "1300" },
            { "Start": "1400", "Finish": "1800" }
        ]
    },
    { "Saturday":
        []
    },
    { "Sunday":
        []
    }
]
}
```

Comment: hi @st3inn, after 4 years would you change this answer ? or still stick with it ? http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification

Comment: I think Brian Campbell raises a good point regarding hours that span multiple days, so I would also take a look at his answer. For a strict daylight schedule, I don't see any big problems with my "old" solution ;)

Answer (score 6):

Following is how Facebook saves the place times

```
"hours": {
    "mon_1_open": "12:00",
    "mon_1_close": "20:30",
    "tue_1_open": "12:00",
    "tue_1_close": "20:30",
    "wed_1_open": "12:00",
    "wed_1_close": "20:30",
    "thu_1_open": "12:00",
    "thu_1_close": "20:30",
    "fri_1_open": "12:00",
    "fri_1_close": "20:30",
    "sat_1_open": "12:00",
    "sat_1_close": "20:30",
    "sun_1_open": "12:00",
    "sun_1_close": "20:30"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

An array of hashes representing time ranges should work. Each one can include a day and time for the opening and closing. I'm just using a number for the time here, as hours since midnight; depending on your needs, a timestamp may work better. I chose to write out the day names, rather than using a number, to avoid confusion over whether you're 0 indexed or 1 indexed and whether you start counting on Sunday or Monday.

```
[{"open": {"day": "monday",
           "time": 9},
  "close": {"day": "monday",
            "time": 13}},
 {"open": {"day": "monday",
           "time": 14},
          {"day": "monday",
           "time": 18}},
 ...]
```

You want to include the day on both ends of the time range, so that you could have hours that span midnight (while you might not expect it now, you may run into a case when someone is open after midnight, or might run into a case in which you want to report on the local time open hours of someone around the world). Other than that, this should be fairly self explanatory.